# How to join two Series type object and make another column in Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Data Frame Transformer contains various columns, Among are Name and Sampling_Point i want to filter and join them to form another column Sample_gas.
i.e,
[image: Sample Table]

Now i had filtered out df.NAME and df.SAMPLING_POINT but now want to join it and assigned it to some other column name called Sample_gas. I had written the code:

```
df['SAMPLE_GAS']=pd.concat([df.NAME,df.SAMPLING_POINT],axis=1)
```

but it give me error like:

> Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1

Please suggest the changes. The output should look like:

[image]

Comment: Please provide a **[mcve]**. This means no images/links, just text. See also [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['SAMPLE_GAS'] = df['NAME'].str.cat(df['SAMPLING_POINT'], sep=' ')
```

Or,

```
df['SAMPLE_GAS'] = [x + ' ' + y for x, y in zip(df['NAME'], df['SAMPLING_POINT'])]
```

For performance.

Comment: Thank you so much for help.

Answer (score 1):

According to your output, you need to simply add your strings,

```
df['SAMPLE_GAS'] = df['NAME'] +' '+ df['SAMPLING_POINT']
```